# wpf animation not working on windows form

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, opencv, emgucv

I am currently working on project which combines emgu cv(as Image Processing) and wpf(2D/3D reconstruction)..

The project first was build in Windows Forms until I find out that if I want to construct 2D/3D object, I have to use WPF control (such as viewport 3D) which will be overlayed on top over the Image Frame/Capture...

So,I used usercontrol to host WPF control in windows form and the code run successfully...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPPbj.png

but, when I tried to make a simple animation(such as the rectangle background color turns into another color,etc), it's not working..

any idea how to solve this problem?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfpGj.png

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="simple_animation">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF21AB49"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#FFAB4721"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#FF21AB49"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource simple_animation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid Margin="0,12,0,0">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF21AB49" Margin="136,93,92,157" Stroke="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

the above code for simple animation.
First you have create Storyboard to animate, then only you can animate which you want to animate.
Please try the above code it will help you well.

Comment: thanks for you answer...but I finally realised that not all wpf functionalities could be invoke in winform.. :)